# Is there any build-in string length support of EcmaScript UTF-16 32-bit Char?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, utf-16

As we know ECMAScript 2015 added `String.fromCodePoint()`
 for 32-bit char.

```
var poop = '';
console.log(poop.length);
```

But if we still use `String.length()`, it will alse treat all chars at string 16 bit. Is there any build-in string length support of EcmaScript UTF-16 32-bit Char?

Answer (score 0):

We can use Destructuring as follows:

```
const poop = '';
console.log([...poop].length);
console.log(Array.from(poop).length);
```

Comment: Using `Array.from` instead of spread syntax would be more idiomatic.